# How to make bash interpreter stop until a command is finished?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with a loop that calls a hard calculation routine every iteration. I use the results from every calculation as input to the next. I need make bash stop the script reading until every calculation is finished.

```
for i in $(cat calculation-list.txt)
do
./calculation
(other commands)
done
```

I know the `sleep` program, and i used to use it, but now the time of the calculations varies greatly.

Thanks for any help you can give.

P.s>
 The "./calculation" is another program, and a subprocess is opened. Then the script passes instantly to next step, but I get an error in the calculation because the last is not finished yet.

Comment: AFAIK Bash scripts are synchronous. Is `./calculation` forking and returning or something?

Comment: What you ask for is the normal way that scripts execute. How are you using the results? Does it modify `calculation-list.txt`? That won't work, because the entire contents of the file are substituted into the `for i` line before any iteration starts.

Comment: The script is not working properly. The "./calculation" is another program, and a subprocess is opened. Then the script passes instantly to next step, but I get an error in the calculation because the last is not finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

If your calculation daemon will work with a precreated empty logfile, then the `inotify-tools` package might serve:

```
touch $logfile
inotifywait  -qqe close $logfile & ipid=$!
./calculation
wait $ipid
```

(edit: stripped a stray semicolon)

if it closes the file just once.

If it's doing an open/write/close loop, perhaps you can mod the daemon process to wrap some other filesystem event around the execution?  `

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uglier, but handles logfile being closed multiple times before exit:

# Have the ./calculation start this shell script, perhaps by substituting 
# this for the program it's starting

trap 'echo >closed-on-calculation-exit' 0 1 2 3 15
./real-calculation-daemon-program
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, guys, I've solved my problem with a different approach. When the calculation is finished a logfile is created. I wrote then a simple `until` loop with a `sleep` command. Although this is very ugly, it works for me and it's enough.

```
for i in $(cat calculation-list.txt)
    do
    (calculations routine)
    until [[ -f $logfile ]]; do
        sleep 60
    done
    (other commands)
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Get the process ID (PID) via some `awk` magic and then use `wait` too wait for that PID to end. Here [are the details on `wait`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html#WAITREF) from the advanced Bash scripting guide:

> Suspend script execution until all jobs running in background have
>   terminated, or until the job number or process ID specified as an
>   option terminates. Returns the exit status of waited-for command.
>
> You may use the wait command to prevent a script from exiting before a
>   background job finishes executing (this would create a dreaded orphan
>   process).

And using it within your code should work like this:

```
for i in $(cat calculation-list.txt)
do
  ./calculation >/dev/null 2>&1 & CALCULATION_PID=(`jobs -l | awk '{print $2}'`);
  wait ${CALCULATION_PID}
  (other commands)
done
```

Comment: Since he's not running `calculation` in the background in the original script, the `wait` command won't help.

Comment: `jobs -p` will return the relevant process IDs more easily, but if all you're doing is passing it into `wait`, you can also just put your jobspec there, or call `wait` with no parameters to wait for all background jobs to finish.